Can we have intellisense on dbt's yml?
I have picked up the dbt cloud tutorial lately, and wanted to dev using vscode. The intellisense kind of works in the sql files, for example when I type ref, then ctrl+space, it will autocomplete to {{ ref('model_name') }}.
Is the same possible with the .yml files? for example typing freshness to have the model for the freshness configuration pop up...
FYI, I have dbt power user.

Thnx to DBT labs for the answers. Please follow discussion in their slack as there are a couple of pending issues with YAML extension. https://getdbt.slack.com/archives/CBSQTAPLG/p1733605614935999

Issue 1 : https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml/issues/1072
Issue 2 : https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml/issues/1073

Yes this is possible - dbt Labs provides a JSON Schema representation of dbt's YAML files. When this extension is installed in your VS Code environment, you can associate the schemas and get autocomplete and type checking.
Full installation instructions are in the above-linked GitHub repo's readme
